# Split No Longer Working When Creating Enclosed Polygons

Tags: geometry, intersection, splitting, arcgis-pro

I have been using ArcGIS Pro to create a large polygon feature class.  Some of the polygons have enclosed areas I need to remove.  I have been using the Split tool under Modify Features and it has been working for weeks. I updated Pro yesterday to 1.2 and didn't have any problems.  Today when I try to use Split to run the same process I have been for weeks I get a message saying

> Split failed. New geometry must intersect polylines and intersect
>   polygons in two or more places.

The Split area I draw is completely enclosed so I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Try running Repair Geometry. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382112/arcgis-pro-and-arcmap-refuse-to-split-a-polygon/ (bothering to add comment because this question came up as a search result when troubleshooting.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a timing issue.
Presumably you're finishing the splitting sketch on the point you started with. If you hover long enough on that end point you'll go into move vertex mode and if you double click then, the split will fail.

For best practice make sure snap to sketch is on (snapping options), create the 'last' point on the start point then move the mouse slightly away before finishing the sketch (F2 or the other shortcuts). If double clicking is also an issue you can turn that off under editor options.
[image]

Comment: These are all the normal practices I use.  For now I am just creating the holes during the creation process by Finishing Part instead of Finishing Sketch. That process doesn't work if an individual polygon has already been completed.